# Can I 'win' with all my crew on board the destroyed final ship?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

In the third Rebel Flagship fight, if all my crew are on board the enemy ship when it gets destroyed, does the game count that as a win (Rebel ship is destroyed) or a loss (all your crew are dead)? Assume I do not have a Clone Bay.

Comment: I can't confirm this, but I've heard that if you destroy yourself and the rebel ship at the same time, it still counts as a win. I'd imagine the same rules apply here.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Actually I've destroyed the rebel ship just as I was destroyed myself, and it counted as a loss.

Comment: I've... never encountered this *exact* situation, but I can confirm that if the [flagship starts breaking apart](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YwU63.png) at any point before the 'game over' message would otherwise be thrown, you are instead treated to a [victory](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TGQoM.png). But in each of those screenshots, my crew is still alive as their ship becomes debris, so I can't say for certain.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You win.

You would also unlock the "Trustworthy Auto-Pilot" achievement for "[defeating] an enemy ship with all of your crew aboard it."

*From the FTL Wikia: "However, it is possible to get this achievement by destroying the final boss with all of your crew on board the enemy ship, resulting in a win with no crew."*

Source: http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Achievements

Comment: You win. But at WHAT COST!?

Comment: They [knew the risks](http://penny-arcade.com/comic/2014/04/28/faster-than-litigation) when they signed up for this.

Comment: Finally got around to trying this (though I did have a depowered Clone Bay). It worked as described, including the Trustworthy Auto-Pilot achievement. The "Credits" screen still listed all of my crew as if they had survived, interestingly.

Comment: One last update -- did this without a Clone Bay. Still a victory, but this time the Credits screen listed an empty crew list (!).